# Xamarin Live Player not updating in realtime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-live-player

Visual studio just came out with an update that's supposed to update the code on your phone in realtime when using xamarin live player. I can get my code to appear on my phone over wifi, but it's not updating my changes.  I select live player and scan the QR code. The app appears on my phone, but doesn't update the code as I type new code. How can I get it to update in realtime?

Relevant article about the feature.

https://blog.xamarin.com/whats-new-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/

Answer (score 8):

You must not deploy the app with the play button but instead use the following key combination to start live preview:

`Shift + Alt + F5`

Comment: On Windows machines (mine, at least) Ctl-F5 is the keystrokes to run without debug, in which case you can watch it continuously rebuild and deploy after you save changes.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer:

Alternatively to [Mazzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2929954/mazzy)s answer. You can Right-Click into your Xaml and Select "Live Run".
That helps in case the ShortCut "Shift + Alt + F5" is not set.

[image: Screenshot of the context Menu showing "Live Run"]

## Further Information:

When starting the Live Run the currently selected view will be deployed and rendered on your device. When you switch to another ui file, the other file will be deployed and rendered.

### Live Update

The live updates only seem to happen, if there is no syntax error and you save the file.

Thanks to [beppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3389585/beppe9000) for the hint

Comment: I clicked the live run link on the yellow bar, but it does not seem to update when I change the XAML code...

Comment: It takes some seconds to update, depending how long it takes to build the changes. If there are some syntax errors, it won't update. And sometimes the livePlayer dies and needs to be restarted.

Comment: I have added that to the answer

Comment: @Adrian which VS version do you use? You may need to activate the LivePlayer in the options of VS in order to use it

Comment: it's latest community edition of 15.7 2017, Thanks I can see it now after pressing SHIFT + ALT + F5